# jQuery: set active class on selected option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add the "active" class in an option element but this code gives it to the select element.

HTML code

```
<select id="category" required >
    <option value="Cats" selected>Cats</option>
    <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
    <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    $("#category").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class to selected option and remove from any other option previously selected like:

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    $('option:selected', this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```css
option:checked {
  background-color:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<select id="category" required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Cats" selected class="active">Cats</option>
  <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
</select>
```

OR

```js
$('#category').change(function() {
  $('option', this).removeClass("active");
  $('option:checked', this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
option.active {
  background-color:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Cats" selected class="active">Cats</option>
  <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
</select>
```